# Prove that there exists $k$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $f(n)\le kn^2$ .

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb N 
\to \mathbb R$ is a function satisfying:

i. for all $n$, $f(n)\le \frac{3n^2}{2}+f\left(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\right) $

ii. $f(0)=0$

Prove that there exists $k$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $f(n)\le kn^2$ .

> My attempt:

$f(0)=0$

$f(1)\le \frac{3}{2}+f(0) =\frac{3}{2}$

$f(2)\le 6+f(1) \le 6+ \frac{3}{2}=\frac{15}{2}$

$f(3)\le \frac{27}{2}+f(1) \le \frac{27}{2}+ \frac{3}{2}=15$

$f(4)\le 24+f(2) \le 24+ \frac{15}{2}=\frac{63}{2}$

$f(5)\le \frac{75}{2}+f(2) \le \frac{75}{2}+ \frac{15}{2}=45$

I see that it might satisfy for some $k$, however i am unable to determine that. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Your computations should suggest the possibility that $k=2$ would work; try to prove this by (strong) induction on $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$f(n) \le kn^2
$
for all $n < m$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
f(m)
&\le \frac{3m^2}{2}+f(\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor)\\
&\le \frac{3m^2}{2}+k(\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor)^2\\
&\le \frac{3m^2}{2}+k(\frac{m}{2})^2\\
&\le \frac{3m^2}{2}+\frac{km^2}{4}\\
&= m^2( \frac{3}{2}+\frac{k}{4})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if 
$\frac{3}{2}+\frac{k}{4}
\le k
$,
then
$f(m) \le km^2
$.

But this is
$\frac32 \le \frac{3k}{4}
$
or
$k \ge 2$.

Since you have shown that
$f(n)
\lt 2n^2$
for
$n \le 5$,
then
$f(n)
\le 2n^2$
for all $n$.

Note that this takes
two steps:

First, find a $k_1$
for which the hypothesis
is true for some initial segment
of the integers.

Second,
find a $k_2$ such that,
for some initial segment
of the integers,
if the hypothesis 
is true for that segment,
then it is true
for all larger integers.

Choosing
$k = \max(k_1, k_2)$
will then work for all integers.